# MediaRecorder: start failed: -2147483648

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

I catch this exception on `23+` api. On api 22 and less, everything works fine. Could you help me please, to find solution?
I am using `23 api` target and tried different configurations, but still have an issue

```
E/MediaRecorder: start failed: -2147483648
W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed. W/System.err: at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
W/System.err: at com.ksy.recordlib.service.recoder.RecoderVideoSource.prepare(RecoderVideoSource.java:105)
W/System.err: at com.ksy.recordlib.service.recoder.RecoderVideoSource.run(RecoderVideoSource.java:173) 
W/System.err: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I found, that reason of the crash is my output

```
 >try {
 >   this.piple = ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe();
 >} catch (IOException e) {
 >   e.printStackTrace();
 >}
 >mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(this.piple[1].getFileDescriptor());
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Record audio is a dangerous permission in marshmallow so you need to check the permission before proceeding otherwise it will throw an exception.

Comment: Thank you! I checked permissions, but exception still exists.

Comment: review the +23 changes required for permissions framework... http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html

Comment: Playing with permissions didn't help. I also used target api 19 and 22. But issue still exists.

Answer (score 4):

Since Android API level = 23 it is no longer possible to use non seekable file descriptors (so also ParcelFileDescriptor) when encoding MPEG4 video. As can be seen in this [commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/2aa74dc097fe860abc84769abf2b6e0962718471%5E%21/media/libstagefright/MPEG4Writer.cpp) MPEG4Writer has been modified to print error and exit when it detects file descriptor that is not seekable.

Pasting mentioned code below for your convenience:

```
// Verify mFd is seekable
off64_t off = lseek64(mFd, 0, SEEK_SET);
if (off < 0) {
    ALOGE("cannot seek mFd: %s (%d)", strerror(errno), errno);
    release();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the MediaRecorder start failed: -2147483648 error
was device and OS level dependent. Usually, the recorder
would start 1 time and subsequent starts would fail.
The fix was to add a call to MediaRecorder.release().
This allowed subsequent starts to work fine.

```
...
try {
   audioRecorderType_MR.stop();
   audioRecorderType_MR.release();  // <<-- ADD THIS LINE
} catch (Exception e) {
   J42CallerId.printStackTrace(new J42ProgramCheck("J42VM0072E:", e));
}
audioRecorderType_MR = null;
...
```